# Is there any way to list out the applications installed in iphone

Tags: iphone

My requirements is i want to do an enterprise application which i need to list all the installed apps in iPhone and also should allow the user to delete some apps from current application.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible without a jailbreak.

All apps are sandboxed so they can't really see anything outside their folder.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible on ios. You cant able to access the information about other application due to sandBoxed environment.

If you want to try, check out this link it may be useful to you

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22289-possible-retrieve-these-information.html